# Mongo reactive repository and Aggregation don't filter results

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am developing a mongo application and I need a paginated method with sorting and filtering. Paging works correctly but the filter using Criteria Aggregations does not work correctly.

My repository methods:

```
public interface FooRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Foo, String> {
    
    Flux<Foo> findBy(Aggregation aggregation, Pageable pageable);
    
    Mono<Long> countBy(Aggregation aggregation);
}
```

And the code of my Service:

```
@Override
public Mono<Page<FooDTO>> findByFilter(FooFilterDTO filter, Pageable pageable) {

    List<MatchOperation> operations = new ArrayList<MatchOperation>();
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(filter.getName())) {
        Criteria regex = Criteria.where("field1").regex( filter.getName(), "i");
        MatchOperation match = new MatchOperation(regex);
        operations.add(match);
    }
    
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(filter.getEmail())) {
        Criteria regex = Criteria.where("field2").regex(filter.getEmail(), "i");
        MatchOperation match = new MatchOperation(regex);
        operations.add(match);
    }
    
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(filter.getSurname())) {
        Criteria regex = Criteria.where("field3").regex(filter.getSurname(), "i");
        MatchOperation match = new MatchOperation(regex);
        operations.add(match);
    }
    
    Aggregation aggregate = Aggregation.newAggregation(Foo.class, operations);
    
    return repository.countBy(aggregate).flatMap(count -> {
        return repository.findBy(aggregate, pageable).collect(Collectors.toList()).flatMap(foos -> {
            return Mono.just(convertPageToDto(new PageImpl<Foo>(foos, pageable, count)));
        });
    });
}
```

The application log shows the following query:

```
findBy() with argument[s] = [{ "aggregate" : "__collection__", "pipeline" : [{ "$match" : { "field1" : { "$regularExpression" : { "pattern" : "John", "options" : "i"}}}}, { "$match" : { "field2" : { "$regularExpression" : { "pattern" : "@", "options" : "i"}}}}, { "$match" : { "field3" : { "$regularExpression" : { "pattern" : "o", "options" : "i"}}}}]}, Page request [number: 0, size 10, sort: name: ASC]]
```

I have tried the following ways but they have not worked:

```
{ "pattern" : "^((?!John).)*$", "options" : "i"}
{ "pattern" : "/John/", "options" : "i"}
{ "pattern" : "/.*John.*/", "options" : "i"}
```

Queries not working with Criteria and ReactiveMongoRepository? I am doing something wrong? any other alternative to filter results using ReactiveMongoRepository and not MongoTemplate?